# Parent logic through PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this php that read some line in xml manipulate then and save and i want to automate this.

```
$convertedXML = new SimpleXMLElement($strXml);
foreach($convertedXML->xpath("task[@id='2'or @id='3']") as $test ) {
  $test->parent = 1;
}
foreach($convertedXML->xpath("task[@id='5'or @id='6' or @id='7' or @id='8' or @id='9' or @id='10']") as $test1 ) {
  $test1->parent = 4;
}
$convertedXML->saveXML("test.xml");
```

My XML is:

```
<data>
    <task id="1">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="2">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="3">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="6">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
</data>
```

The result that i want is:

```
<data>
    <task id="1">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="2">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="3">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="6">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
</data>
```

Any suggestions? I´ve also tried to do this with xslt with no success.

Comment: What is `$test->parent = 1;` ? tasks have no parent, as i see

Comment: Parent is a child tag of task...

Comment: I want to automate this... like not guessing the $test->parent = 1 and guessing the id numbers too...

Comment: Hi Nelson, please explain in more detail and give an example of how the result should look like. Then describe what you have tried and what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this?

Original data:

```
$strXml = '<data>
    <task id="1">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="2">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="3">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="6">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="7">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="8">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="9">
        <parent>-1</parent>
    </task>
</data>';
```

Code:

```
$convertedXML = new SimpleXMLElement($strXml);
$i = 0;
foreach($convertedXML as $task) {
    if($convertedXML->task[$i]) {
        $id = (string) $task["id"];
        $parent = (string) $task->parent;
        $task->parent = ($parent == 0) ? 0 : $back_parent;
        $back_parent = ($parent == 0) ? $id : $back_parent;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo $convertedXML->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<data>
    <task id="1">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="2">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="3">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="6">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="7">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="8">
        <parent>7</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="9">
        <parent>7</parent>
    </task>
</data>
```

Edit in: http://ideone.com/sVCQYd

Comment: @GiovanniMesquita Cool! Not about the code, is is usual (moreover, you don't need two loops, make `$task->parent = ($parent == 0) ? 0 : $back_parent;`). But how you understood the task :)) !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// array id => new parent value
$set = array(0,0,1,1,0,4,4,4,4,4,4);

$convertedXML = new SimpleXMLElement($strXml);
foreach($convertedXML->task as $task) {
   $attrs = $task->attributes();
   $i = (int)$attrs['id'];
   if ($i < count($set))                    // if id is in array
        $task->parent = $set[$i];           // set new value
}

echo $convertedXML->saveXML();
```

result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <task id="1">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="2">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="3">
        <parent>1</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="4">
        <parent>0</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="5">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
    <task id="6">
        <parent>4</parent>
    </task>
</data>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This almost solved my problem!! Is it possible to do without the array?? Because the numbers can change in parent...

Comment: *Without array* - i don't understand where you will take new value

Comment: Because the numbers of parent can change, for example... <task id="1"> <parent>0</parent> <task id="2"> <parent>0</parent> <task id="3"> <parent>2</parent>

Comment: ok. but you must know new value of parenf for every id. Array only to save them

Comment: The new value of the array is possible to be the last value with parent = 0?? And set this into an array??

Comment: Array is such : key is id, value is new value of parent. if yuo want  for  id=5 change value to 12, do  `$set[5] = 12;`

Comment: Can i set a variable with a last value of id for parent = 0?

Comment: I don't understan what is ` the  last value of id for parent = 0` :(

Comment: For example the task id "5" the parent  is 4, right?? 4 is the last value of the task "id" where parent is 0.

Comment: ie, you want to find the last parent 0? use xpath `(//task[parent = 0])[last()]`